# UIImage Caching causing Localization issues at runtime

Tags: ios, localization, nsbundle

I am trying to load a .xib based on the language selected by the user at the runtime.

To get the particular Bundle I use the following code

```
-(NSBundle*) getMyBundle{
    NSArray *languages=[NSLocale preferredLanguages];
    NSString *basePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Base" ofType:@"lproj"];
    if(languages.count){
        NSString *langKey=[languages objectAtIndex:0];
        if(![util checkIfStringIsEmpty:langKey]){
            NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:langKey ofType:@"lproj"];
            if(![util checkIfStringIsEmpty:path]){
                return [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];;
            }
        }
    }

   return [NSBundle bundleWithPath:basePath];
}


-(void) loadMyController{
    AViewController *controller=[[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AViewController" bundle:[self getMyBundle]];

[self.navigationController  pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

So, with above code .xib are loaded correctly , but since images are cached, they are not picked up.

So, any solution to overcome this issue will be a great help.

Comment: Have you tick your images for the bundle?

Comment: yes, Image's are localized and respective bundle has required images.